# OpenGL Vertex Attributes, position works but texcoord doesn't?

Tags: shader, vertex-attributes, go-gl

Vertex shader:

```
#version 130

in vec2 position;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec3 Color;
out vec2 Texcoord;

void main() {
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 130

in vec2 Texcoord;
uniform sampler2D texImage;

void main()
{
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texImage, Texcoord);
}
```

Where I initialize my image:

```
func initImage() {
    gl.UseProgram(texProgram)
    var vao uint32
    gl.GenVertexArrays(1, &vao)
    gl.BindVertexArray(vao)
    imgQuadData := []float32{
        -.5, .5, 0, 0, // Top Left
        .5, .5, 1, 0, // Top Right
        .5, -.5, 1, 1, // Bottom Right
        -.5, -.5, 0, 1, // Bottom Left
    }

    gl.GenBuffers(1, &imgQuadBuffer)
    gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, imgQuadBuffer)
    gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(imgQuadData)*4, gl.Ptr(imgQuadData), gl.STATIC_DRAW)

    posAttrib = gl.GetAttribLocation(texProgram, gl.Str("position\x00"))
    gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(uint32(posAttrib))
    gl.VertexAttribPointer(uint32(posAttrib), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*4, gl.Ptr(nil))

    texAttrib = gl.GetAttribLocation(texProgram, gl.Str("texcoord\x00"))
    gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(uint32(texAttrib))
    ptr := 2 * 4
    gl.VertexAttribPointer(uint32(texAttrib), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*4, gl.Ptr(&ptr))

    pixels := []float32{
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, // Red / Green
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, // Blue / White
    }
    gl.ActiveTexture(gl.TEXTURE0)
    gl.GenTextures(1, &bcTexture)
    gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, bcTexture)
    gl.TexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, 2, 2, 0, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, gl.Ptr(&pixels[0]))
    gl.Uniform1i(gl.GetUniformLocation(texProgram, gl.Str("texImage\x00")), 0)

    gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
    gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
}
```

Where I draw to screen:

```
gl.ClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1)
gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
gl.UseProgram(texProgram)
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, imgQuadBuffer)
gl.DrawArrays(gl.QUADS, 0, 4)
```

On the laptop I'm running on 1.30 is the latest GLSL language version supported so I can't move up to a newer version.

`imgQuadData` holds the X/Y position of where to draw a corner of the quad as well as what the S/T values for texture coordinates at that corner should be. I've followed [this tutorial](https://open.gl/textures) to get to what I have. Although I'm working in go, the go-gl library makes it pretty trivial to convert C++ GL calls to go GL calls.

[image: red square on yellow background]

It's behaving as if `Texcoord` in the fragment shader is always `vec2(0, 0)`. If I change that line in the fragment shader to use `vec2(1, 1)` instead of `Texcoord` then the square changes colors properly. The problem seems to be that `imgQuadData` isn't being parsed properly for the vertex shader to get the S and T values as non-0 values and I don't understand why.

How can my position attributes be read successfully but my texcoord attributes always equal 0?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when specifying the last parameter in `gl.VertexAttribPointer` you should use `gl.PtrOffset` instead of `gl.Ptr`. I guess what GL was seeing with `gl.Ptr` was some large address when it should have been 8 (skip the first 2 floats that are of size 4).

[image: proper color blur]